# Determine user location on iOS Simulator with React Native app using Geolocation API

Tags: react-native

How can make the app that will be run on the iOS simulator get the geolocation.

Currently I can only get the error output I have written for the error callback for the getCurrentPosition() or the watchPosition().

I have this code in one of my components:

```
 componentDidMount: function(){
    var geo = navigator.geolocation;
    var positionOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 3000,
      maximumAge: 0,
    };
    var success = function(position){
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        },
      });
    };
    var error = function(error){
      alert('error watchposition:', error.code);
    };
    var watchID = geo.watchPosition(success, error, positionOptions);
    // geo.getCurrentPosition(success, error, positionOptions);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a correct custom location in the debug menu for the simulator.

Also make sure location services enabled in the simulator for your app.

Comment: I had enabled the location services on the simulator.

Comment: what are the coords of your custom location?

Comment: Since I have given up that set up  for a while I cannot remember the custom location in it. Once I start work on it again I can tell. The thing here is that can ios simulator get real location?

Comment: Maybe it does not supposed to work on simulator which I was thinking as a possibility.